# Swift: How to use instanceType in callback closure

Tags: swift

I want to pass `self` as `instancetype` to the callback closure of this function:

```
extension UIView {
    public func onTap(_ handler: @escaping (_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer, _ view: Self) -> Void) -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
        ...
    }
}

let view = UIView.init()
view.onTap { tap, v in
    ...
}
```

But I got an error:

```
Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class; did you mean 'UIView'?
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

that is just the perfect scenario (by book) when you can use *protocols* and *extensions* in Swift quite efficiently:

```
protocol Tappable { }

extension Tappable { // or alternatively: extension Tappable where Self: UIView {
    func onTap(_ handler: @escaping (UITapGestureRecognizer, Self) -> Void) -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
        return UITapGestureRecognizer() // as default to make this snippet sane
    }
}

extension UIView: Tappable { }
```

---

then for e.g.:

```
let button = UIButton.init()
button.onTap { tap, v in
    // v is UIButton...
}
```

while for e.g.:

```
let label = UILabel.init()
label.onTap { tap, v in
    // v is UILabel...
}
```

etc...

---

***NOTE:*** you can read more about [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) or the [Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) in the [Swift Programming Language Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) from Apple.